# What is causing java.lang.ArithmeticException in Facebook Ads SDK

Tags: android, google-play, admob, facebook-ads-api

I'm getting the Crash below from my Google Play Console. Even with uploaded Deobfuscation files, I can't figure out where in the app, the crash is taking place.
I'm showing Facebook Interstitial Ads in two places in my app and also in a Banner under mediation with Admob.
Any pointers will be appreciated

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException:  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.d.b.i$2.a(i.java)
  at <OR> com.facebook.ads.internal.view.d.b.i$2.a (i.java)
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.d.b.i$2.a (i.java)
  at <OR> com.facebook.ads.internal.view.d.b.i$2.a (i.java)
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.g.r.b (r.java)
  at <OR> com.facebook.ads.internal.g.r.b (r.java)
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.g.r.a (r.java)
  at <OR> com.facebook.ads.internal.g.r.a (r.java)
  at <OR> com.facebook.ads.internal.g.r.a (r.java)
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.o$1.run (o.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5401)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:919)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:714)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was able to fix it by downgrading from version 4.25.0 to version 4.23.0 of the SDK:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.23.0'
```

Comment: What about version 4.24.0? Does it have the bug as well?

Comment: I am not sure. I think I will just wait for the next version, since I do not want risking more crashes.